# PayPal Website Payments Standard Integration

Tags: paypal, web, integration, standards, payment

I am integrating a basic HTML form with the most basic level of PayPal - Website Payments Standard. It might be a silly question but how do you tell PayPal which account to pay? Is it through this line:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremailaddress@yourdomain.com" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. it would be better to use the unique account ID but the account email address will work. Email addresses must be confirmed.